# How to understand "feature extraction" weights in simple Tensorflow/Keras neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

**I'm trying to make the most basic of basic neural networks to get familiar with feature extraction in Tensorflow 2.x and, in particular, keras.**

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following with my simplified iris dataset (i.e. setosa or not)

Use the 4 features as input
Dense layer of 3
Sigmoid activation function
Dense layer of 2 (one for each class)
Softmax activation
Binary cross entropy / log-loss as my loss function

Here's how I build the neural network (Note, the performance is terrible but I'm just using this a toy example):

```
# Load data
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

iris = load_iris()
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
X = X.astype("float32")
X.index = X.index.map(lambda i: "iris_{}".format(i))
X.columns = X.columns.map(lambda j: j.split(" (")[0].replace(" ","_"))
y.index = X.index
y = y.map(lambda i:iris.target_names[i])
y_simplified = y.map(lambda i: {True:1, False:0}[i == "setosa"])
Y = pd.get_dummies(y_simplified, columns=["setosa", "not_setosa"])

# Traing test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
seed=0
X_train,X_test, Y_train,Y_test= train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)

# Simple neural network
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed)


# Input[4 features] -> Dense layer of 3 neurons -> Activation function -> Dense layer of 2 (one per class) -> Softmax
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.sigmoid)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="simple_binary_iris")
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=[ "accuracy"] )
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

Here's the summary:

```
Model: "simple_binary_iris"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 4)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 15        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 8         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 23
Trainable params: 23
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here's the feature extraction code from [keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction):

```
# https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction
extractor = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=model.inputs, 
    outputs=[layer.output for layer in model.layers],
)
features = extractor(X_train.values)
list(map(lambda weights: weights.shape, features))
# [TensorShape([105, 4]),
#  TensorShape([105, 3]),
#  TensorShape([105, 3]),
#  TensorShape([105, 2]),
#  TensorShape([105, 2])]
```

**What I understand is the following:**

1. `features[0]` are the input values of `X_train`
2. `features[1]` are the weights of the first dense layer
3. `features[2]` are the weights of the dense layer after the sigmoid activation function
4. `features[3]` are the weights of the second dense layer
5. `features[4]` are the weights of the second dense layer after the softmax activation function

**What I don't understand is the following:**

1. How do I know the value of each feature's contribution in the input layer (4 features) to the first dense layer weight?
2. Shouldn't there be a matrix somewhere that is 4 x 3 = 12 weights showing the contribution of each of the 4 features to each of the 3 neurons in the first dense layer?

Without this type of understanding, this algorithm is pretty much a black box.

Comment: Your premise is wrong, the features vector does not contain any weight values, it just contains the output of each layer given your input.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate a bit . I’m a little confused by what you mean. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: The variable called features does not have anything in content that can be called weights

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy can you elaborate more? What are they then?  You're second response was saying the same thing as the first essentially.  Can you give details? I'm trying to understand what these values are

Comment: Do you understand what weights mean in the context of a neural network?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy "Weights are the co-efficients of the equation which you are trying to resolve." https://medium.com/fintechexplained/neural-networks-bias-and-weights-10b53e6285da.  For example, if a logistic regression is a simple one layer neural network with a logit activation function, the coefficients would be the weights.

Comment: I was asking if you understood, not a textbook definition. In your code you are computing output features of each layer, using your definition of weight, the weights are the coefficients or parameters inside each layer, not the output of the layer itself. But the weights are used to compute the output of each layer.

Comment: 1/ Let me help you there: consider a layer which consists of one neuron which takes its input, multiplies it by a trainable-parameter and adds it to a trainable-parameter, and produces this result as its output. In other words, that layer could be shown with `y = a*x + b` where `x` is the input, `a` and `b` are the trainable-parameters (i.e. weights) and `y` is the output of this layer. Now, in Keras when you apply a model on an input, you would get the output of layer(s) and not their weights; i.e. `layer.output` is the output (i.e. `y` as before) of the layer.

Comment: 2/ But the weights or parameters of a layer are independent of the input of the layer and belong to the layer itself (e.g. in our example, you cannot obtain value of `y` without feeding `x` with a value; but `a` and `b` always exist and have a value - at the beginning their values would be initialized randomly and then during training their value converge to the optimal value). So to get the weights of a layer we use `layer.get_weights()` independently (i.e. without the need to apply the model on a set of input).

Comment: 3/ Alternatively, in recent versions of `keras` or `tf.keras`, we can also use `layer.weights` to obtain the weights. Also this [short description](https://keras.io/api/layers/) of layers API in Keras might help you to get a better idea.

Comment: @today thank you this is extremely helpful.  I was misusing some phrases but I understand now.  Are there any special terms for the output values?

Comment: @today does this seem to sum up getting the contribution of weights per neuron in the first dense layer? https://pastebin.com/0cN3asZJ

Comment: The output of a layer given an input is generally called activation.

Comment: What goes into the layer/model is called input and what comes out is called output or activation. The trainable-parameters of a layer/model are usually called weights. Also, those parameters which are not learned but determined by us (e.g. the number of neurons in a layer, the activation function of a layer, the learning rate of optimizer, the number of layers in a model, etc.) are called hyper-parameters (you might have heard of hyper-parameter tuning which aims to find the best hyper-parameters; Keras has a specific package for that: [keras-tuner](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner)).

Comment: Regarding the code snippet: yeah, it is dividing the weights of each neuron in the first layer attributed to all input features (each single element of the input may be called a feature) by their sum such that for each neuron its weights sum to 1. It's one way of finding out how each neuron is attributing importance to different input features.